# Activate hover color after toggle function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have read a lot of posts here but I can't find the solution.. Any ideas why hover color doesn't work on second click? (example with snippet or jsfiddle please) Thanks!!!

```js
function toggleButton() {
  var button = document.getElementById('toggle').style.backgroundColor;
  var color = '';

if (button !== 'pink') {
  color = 'pink';
document.getElementById('toggle').style.backgroundColor = color;
document.getElementById('toggle').style.color = "#222";

} else if (button === 'pink') {
  color = '#2c475c';
document.getElementById('toggle').style.backgroundColor = color;
document.getElementById('toggle').style.color = "#fff";
  }
}
```

```css
#toggle {    
  padding: 20px 45px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius:5px;
  font-weight:600; 
}

#toggle:hover {  
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<button  id="toggle" onclick="toggleButton();">TOGGLE</button >
```

Comment: when you set style via javascript, it is included into a style attribute, which overwrites any other style you set from a style sheet. Instead setting new style, add a class `classList.add('myNewClass')` , so it can be parts of the style sheet with rules that are not the most important ones.

Answer (score 2):

from comment

> when you set style via javascript, it is included into a style attribute, which overwrites any other style you set from a style sheet. Instead setting new style, add a class classList.add('myNewClass') , so it can be parts of the style sheet with rules that are not the most important ones

example

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  if (this.classList.contains('pink')) {
      this.classList.toggle('darkblue');
    }
    this.classList.toggle('pink');
  };
```

```css
#toggle {
  padding: 20px 45px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#toggle:hover,
#toggle.pink:hover,
#toggle.darkblue:hover{
  background: aqua;
}

#toggle.pink {
  background-color: pink;
  color: #222;
}

#toggle.darkblue {
  background: #2c475c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button >
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the background with [inline style](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/html-inline-styles), which has greater specificity than your CSS. If you want to override any inline style, you have to make your style in CSS `!important`.

```css
#toggle:hover {  
  background: aqua !important;
}
```

### Edit

As mentioned by [@G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/g-cyrillus), the better way is to create classes with the color you need for the button and toggle those classes (and not inline style). For you code, it would be good to create 2 classes: for `pink` and `grey`.

```css
.pink {
  color: #222;
  background-color: pink;
}
.grey {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2c475c;
}
```

Now you just need to edit your JS file, so it works with your new classes.

```js
function toggleButton() {
  var button = document.getElementById("toggle");

  if (button.classList.contains("grey")) {
    button.classList.remove("grey");
    button.classList.add("pink");
  } else {
    button.classList.remove("pink");
    button.classList.add("grey");
  }
}
```

And because `:hover` [has greater specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than plain `pink` or `grey` class, it will trigger your hover styles.

Comment: Note that !important can be a drag and is a bad practise in general. You better add/remove class via js to avoid this kind of situation ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Of course, that's a good point! I'll put in the answer;)